# tex4ebook: bookmarks are duplicated when titlesec package is imported

Tags: titlesec, bookmarks, tex4ebook

I'm generating an .epub with tex4ebook and I need to use titlesec. When I compiled the document, I noticed that if I import titlesec and compile more than once, the bookmarks for sections and subsections are duplicated. Any hints for how to remove the duplicates would be appreciated.

mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\part{Mammalia}
\chapter{Monotremata}
\section{Platypoda}
\subsection{Ornithorhynchidae}
\subsubsection{Ornithorhynchus}
\paragraph{anatinus}
\section{Tachyglossa}
\subsection{Tachyglossidae}
\subsubsection{Tachyglossus}
\paragraph{aculeatus}

\end{document}
```

mwe.mk4

```
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local ncxprocess = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    for i, navpoint in ipairs(dom:query_selector("navPoint")) do
       local text = navpoint:query_selector("text")[1]:get_text():gsub("^%s*", ""):gsub("%s*$", ""):lower()
       if dom:query_selector("navPoint")[i+1] ~= nil then
         local next_nav = dom:query_selector("navPoint")[i+1]
         local next_text = next_nav:query_selector("text")[1]:get_text():gsub("^%s*", ""):gsub("%s*$", ""):lower()
         if next_text == text then
           navpoint:remove_node()
         end
       end
    end
    return dom
  end
}

Make:htlatex {}
Make:htlatex {}
Make:match("ncx$", ncxprocess)
```

Output when titlesec import is commented out:

[image]

.ncx file when titlesec is not imported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <!DOCTYPE ncx PUBLIC "-//NISO//DTD ncx 2005-1//EN" 
"http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx-2005-1.dtd"> 
 <ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">                                                                              <head> 
 <meta name="dtb:uid" content="http://example.com/mwe"/> 
 <meta name="dtb:depth" content="3"/> 
 <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/> 
 <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/> 
 </head> 

<docTitle> 
<text>Unnamed</text> 
</docTitle> 
 <navMap>       
<navPoint id="navPoint-1" playOrder="1"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="part">  I</navmark> Mammalia</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwepa1.html#x2-1000I" />        
<navPoint id="navPoint-2" playOrder="2"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="chapter">  1</navmark> Monotremata</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-20001" />        
<navPoint id="navPoint-3" playOrder="3"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="section">  1.1</navmark> Platypoda</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-30001.1" />
 
<navPoint id="navPoint-4" playOrder="4"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="subsection">  1.1.1</navmark> Ornithorhynchidae</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-40001.1.1" />  </navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
     
<navPoint id="navPoint-5" playOrder="5"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="section">  1.2</navmark> Tachyglossa</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-70001.2" />       
<navPoint id="navPoint-6" playOrder="6"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="subsection">  1.2.1</navmark> Tachyglossidae</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-80001.2.1" />
   </navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
</navMap>

   </ncx>
```

Output when titlesec is imported:

[image]

.ncx file when titlesec is imported:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <!DOCTYPE ncx PUBLIC "-//NISO//DTD ncx 2005-1//EN" 
"http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx-2005-1.dtd"> 
 <ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">                                                                                  <head> 
 <meta name="dtb:uid" content="http://example.com/mwe"/> 
 <meta name="dtb:depth" content="3"/> 
 <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/> 
 <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/> 
 </head> 
 <docTitle> 
<text>Unnamed</text> 
</docTitle> 

<navMap>     
<navPoint id="navPoint-1" playOrder="1"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="part">  I</navmark> Mammalia</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwepa1.html#x2-1000I" />        
<navPoint id="navPoint-2" playOrder="2"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="chapter">  1</navmark> Monotremata</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-20001" />        
<navPoint id="navPoint-3" playOrder="3"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="section">  1.1</navmark> Platypoda</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-30001" />  </navPoint> 
      
<navPoint id="navPoint-4" playOrder="4"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="section">  </navmark>
1.1                                                 Platypoda</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#Q1-3-4" />       
<navPoint id="navPoint-5" playOrder="5"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="subsection">  1.1.1</navmark>
Ornithorhynchidae</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-40001" /> </navPoint> 
     
<navPoint id="navPoint-6" playOrder="6"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="subsection"> </navmark> 1.1.1
Ornithorhynchidae</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#Q1-3-6" />     </navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
              
<navPoint id="navPoint-7" playOrder="7"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="section">     1.2</navmark>   Tachyglossa</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-70002" />     </navPoint> 
              
<navPoint id="navPoint-8" playOrder="8"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="section">     </navmark>
1.2                                                 Tachyglossa</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#Q1-3-12" />      
<navPoint id="navPoint-9" playOrder="9"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="subsection">  1.2.1</navmark>
Tachyglossidae</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#x3-80001" />  </navPoint> 
     
<navPoint id="navPoint-10" playOrder="10"> 
<navLabel> 
<text><navmark type="subsection">  </navmark> 1.2.1
Tachyglossidae</text> 
</navLabel> 
<content src="mwech1.html#Q1-3-14" />
   </navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
</navPoint> 
</navMap>
   </ncx>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version of `titlesec.4ht`:

```
% titlesec.4ht (2020-11-20-14:29), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2000-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2020-11-20-14:29}

\ifx \ttl@assign@ii\:Undef
   \ifx \ttl@sect\:UnDef\else
     \pend:defII\ttl@sect{%
  \@ifstar {}{\SkipRefstepAnchor}}
\let\ttl:select=\ttl@select
\def\ttl@select#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \edef\sc:tp{\ifttl@label\else like\fi #1}\def\c:secnumdepth{#5}%
  \ttl:select{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\let\ttl@write\:gobbleIII

   \fi
   \ifx \ttl@useclass\:UnDef\else
     \pend:defII\ttl@useclass{%
  \@ifstar {}{\SkipRefstepAnchor}}
\let\ttl:select\ttl@select
\def\ttl@select#1{%
  \edef\sc:tp{\ifttl@label\else like\fi
             #1}\def\c:secnumdepth{\@nameuse{ttll@#1}}%
  \ttl:select{#1}}
\let\ttl@write\:gobbleII
\let\ttl@glcmds\relax
\let\ttl@beginlongest\@empty
\let\ttl@midlongest\@empty
\let\ttl@endlongest\@empty

   \fi
   \let\ttlh:hang\ttlh@hang
\def\ttlh@hang#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
   \HtmlEnv
   \expandafter\def\csname thetitle\sc:tp\endcsname{#2}%
   \csname no:\sc:tp\endcsname{#8}%
   \par \ttlh:hang{}{}{#3}{}{}{#6}{#7}{}}
\let\:seccntformat=\@seccntformat
\def\@seccntformat#1{\ifnum 0=0\the\csname c@#1\endcsname\else
   \:seccntformat{#1}\fi}

\else
   \let\ttl:straight@i\ttl@straight@i
\def\ttl@straight@i#1[#2]#3{%
  \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
%
  \ifttl@label \else
     \def\:temp{#1}\edef\:tempa{\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\:gobble
    \expandafter\string\csname section\endcsname}\ifx \:temp\:tempa \else
       \edef\:tempa{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:gobble
  \expandafter\string\csname subsection\endcsname}\ifx \:temp\:tempa \else
     {\ttl@labeltrue \ttl@addcontentsline{like#1}{#3}}%
\fi
%
\fi
%
  \fi
  \edef\sc:tp{\ifttl@label\else like\fi #1}%
  \ttl:straight@i{#1}[{#2}]{#3}%
}
\def\ttlh@hang#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
   \def\c:secnumdepth{\@nameuse{ttll@\sc:tp}}%
   \:StartSec {\sc:tp}{%
         \ifttl@label \ifnum \c:secnumdepth >\c@secnumdepth
         \else \csname the\sc:tp\endcsname \fi \fi
       }{#8}%
}
\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
  \let\everypar\@gobble% don't let titlesec to break our paragraph handling
  \edef\sc:tp{\ifttl@label\else like\fi #1}%
   \let\ttl@savewrite\empty
   \o:ttl@select:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
   \endgroup
}

\HLet\ttl@select\:tempc
\let\ttlh@runin\ttlh@hang
\let\ttlh@display\ttlh@hang

\fi
\def\ttl@addcontentsline#1#2{%
  \nobreak}
\Hinput{titlesec}
\endinput
```

It seems that Titlesec adds each section or subsection (not chapter or part) explicitly to TOC, but TeX4ht does this as well, so you get duplicate entries.

We can disable Titlesec's code that adds them to TOC using this redefinition:

```
\def\ttl@addcontentsline#1#2{%
  \nobreak}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks :)